# Quick way to prove $\mathbb R^n-\{O\}$ is connected?

Tags: general-topology

I want to show that the $n$-sphere is path connected, when $n>0$, and I've reduced it to showing/assuming that, if $n>1$, $\mathbb R^n-\{O\}$ is connected. Is there a quick way to prove this? I can assume that $\mathbb R^n$ is connected, I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take any two points $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb{R}^n\backslash\{O\}$. If the line segment
$$f(\alpha)=\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y$$
never passes through zero (for $\alpha\in[0,1]$), then $x$ and $y$ are clearly connected. This can only happen if $x=cy$ for some negative $c$. Clearly, if $x=cy$, there must be some vector $z$ not parallel to either (since otherwise $\{x\}$ would be a basis, but the space has dimension greater than 1). Thus, both $x$ and $y$ would be connected to $z$, and hence connected to each other. Since $x$ and $y$ were chosen arbitrarily, $\mathbb{R}^n\backslash\{O\}$ is connected. (More generally and by the same argument $\mathbb{R}^n\backslash A$ for some $n-2$ dimensional or less subspace $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is always connected)

Comment: Thanks. This also prevents me from having to use "open in $\mathbb R^n$ and connected implies path connected."

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to show it's path-connected, which is strictly stronger than connected.  Given any two points in the sphere,  if they are not on opposite sides of the origin,  draw the straight line path.  If they are on opposite sides of the origin, then draw a bent path around the origin.

Answer (score 1):

$f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^2\setminus \{0\}$ with $f(x,y)=(xy,xy+1)$ is continuous and surjective and thus the continuous image of $f$, $\mathbb R^2\setminus \{0\}$ is connected.
Just a quick thought. Correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: It's definitely continuous, but I think showing surjectiveness is far harder than is necessary for this problem

Comment: @Alan $(a,b)\in \mathbb R^2\setminus \{0\}$ then if $x,y\neq 0$, $xy=a=>x=a/y=>b=a+1$

Comment: ok, not that hard :)

Answer (score 0):

Let $S_1$ and $S_2$ are $n-1$ dimensional circle in $R^n$ centered at the origin with different radius. You can see that the line $y=ax$ connect $S_1$ and $S_2$, and the circles are connected for $n>1$ so we are done. (any two points lives on such circles)

Answer (score 0):

$$
\mathbb{R}^n\backslash\{O\} \cong \mathbb{S}^{n-1} \times (0,\infty)
$$

Comment: killing a fly with atomic bomb.

Comment: just a snapshot

Comment: a snapshot of a dying fly.

Comment: I'm pretty sure proving this, if it wasn't given as a fact, is far more complicated than showing path-connected :)